# What is the result of decltype("Hello")?

Tags: c++, c++11, string-literals, decltype

I'm getting unexpected results from all compilers on which I tried the following (GCC 4.7.2, GCC 4.8.0 beta, ICC 13.0.1, Clang 3.2, VC10):

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    // This will fire
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<decltype("Hello"), char const[6]>::value, 
        "Error!"
        );
}
```

I would have expected the compile-time assertion above *not* to fire, but it does. After all, this one does not (as expected):

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    char const hello[6] = "Hello";

    // This will not fire
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<decltype(hello), char const[6]>::value, 
        "Error!"
        );
}
```

So what is the result of `decltype("Hello")` according to the C++11 Standard (references are highly appreciated)? What should I compare it to so that the compile-time assertion above doesn't fire?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

[*Note: Originally, this was not meant to be a self-answered question; I just happened to find the answer myself while I was describing my attempts to investigate, and I thought it would have been nice to share it.*]

According to Annex C (2.14.5) of the C++11 Standard:

> The type of a string literal is changed from “array of char” to “**array of const char**.” [....]

Moreover, Paragraph 7.1.6.2/4 specifies (about the result of `decltype`):

> The type denoted by `decltype(e)` is defined as follows:
>
> — if `e` is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access (5.2.5), `decltype(e)` is the type of the entity named by `e`. If there is no such entity, or if `e` names a set of overloaded functions, the program is ill-formed;
>
> — otherwise, if `e` is an xvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;
>
> — **otherwise, if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`**;
>
> — otherwise, `decltype(e)` is the type of `e`.

Since **[string literals are lvalues](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/15036281/c11-value-category-of-string-literal/15036305#15036305)**, according to the above Paragraph and the Paragraph from Annex C, the result of `decltype("Hello")` is an ***lvalue reference to*** an array of size 6 of constant narrow characters:

```
#include <type_traits>

int main()
{
    // This will NOT fire
    static_assert(
        std::is_same<decltype("Hello"), char const (&)[6]>::value, 
        "Error!"
        );
}
```

Finally, even though the `hello` variable *is* also an lvalue, the second compile-time assertion  from the question's text does not fire, because `hello` is an *unparenthesized id-expression*, which makes it fall into the first item of the above list from Paragraph 7.1.6.2/4. Therefore, the result of `decltype(hello)` is the type of the entity named by `hello`, which is `char const[6]`.

Comment: These rules make sense when you think about writing `decltype(expr) &&`.

Comment: @KerrekSB: Yes. I just found it surprising because I am kind of used to think in the gross terms of "a string literal has type `const char[]`, `decltype(x)` returns the type of `x`, so `decltype("hello")` should return `const char[6]`", forgetting the details. Lesson learnt (hopefully)

Comment: +1 both to the question and to the answer. I promise I never touch a C++ compiler anymore.

Comment: @AndyProwl You said you got different results with the various compilers you listed; it would be great if you could provide what the compilers you tested did.

Comment: @Valloric: The results I get from all compilers are the same, and they are *correct*: the assertion fires. I was just having the wrong expectation, since I was expecting the assert not to fire. That's what I meant by "unexpected results". The answer should clear it up.