# C++: Why is 'operator+=' defined but not 'operator+' for strings?

Tags: c++, string, c++11, operators

How come `operator+=` is defined for `std::string` but `operator+` is not defined? See my MWE below (http://ideone.com/OWQsJk).

```
#include <iostream>
#include <string>
using namespace std;

int main() {  
    string first;
    first = "Day";
    first += "number";
    cout << "\nfirst = " << first << endl;

    string second;
    //second = "abc" + "def";       // This won't compile
    cout << "\nsecond = " << second << endl;
    return 0;
}
```

Comment: You expect: `"abc"->operator+("def")` to work?

Comment: @crashmstr Well I can see why they would. It would in many other languages (that is, string literals are a class type).

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to convert one of the raw string literals to `std::string` explicitly. You can do it like others already mentioned:

```
second = std::string("abc") + "def";
```

or with C++14, you will be able to use

```
using namespace std::literals;
second = "abc"s + "def";
// note       ^
```

Answer (score 6):

Those aren't `std::string`s, they are `const char *`. Try this:

```
 second = std::string("abc") + "def";
```

Comment: Technically they're not `const char*`, they're `const char[4]`.

Comment: @MooingDuck And non-technically too :-)

Comment: @MooingDuck Technically technically they're `const char (&)[4]`.

Comment: @0x499602D2: I almost typed that, but I then assumed that literals are not references, they are values.  Tested just now, it does indeed bind to a mutable reference, so I guess you're right that they're references: http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/b60f5bc56c82e568.  Actually, maybe they're just lvalues?  I dunno.

Comment: @MooingDuck No, it's still a reference. [See this.](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15047277/what-is-the-result-of-decltypehello) :)

Comment: @0x499602D2 From your link: "The type of a string literal is changed... to array of const char." "if `e` is an lvalue, `decltype(e)` is `T&`, where `T` is the type of `e`;"  That's pretty clear that the type of `e` is `T` and NOT a reference.  `decltype("literal")` is a reference, but `"literal"` is merely an lvalue.

Answer (score 4):

> C++: Why is 'operator+=' defined but not 'operator+' for strings?

It is. It requires at least one of the operands to be an `std::string`:

```
int main() 
{
  std::string foo("foo");
  std::string bar("bar");
  std::string foobar = foo + bar;
  std::cout << foobar << std::endl;
}
```

The problem in your case is that you are trying to add string literals `"abc"` and `"def"`. These have type `const char[4]`. There is no `operator+` for these types.

Answer (score 0):

`+`  will work to concatenate two strings only when at least one  operand is of type `std::string`.

In `"abc" + "def"`, None of the operand is of type `std::string`.