# Why does decltype on a string literal not yield an array type?

Tags: c++, arrays, string, c++11, decltype

The standard defines a string literal's type, in §2.13.5/8, as:

> Ordinary string literals and UTF-8 string literals are also referred to as narrow string literals. A narrow string literal has type “array of n const char”, where n is the size of the string as defined below, and has static storage duration (3.7).

Therefore, for example, `"sss"` should have a type `char const[4]` (unless I'm reading it incorrectly).

But this simple snippet:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_pointer<decltype("sss")>::value << '\n';
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_array<decltype("sss")>::value;
```

[gives](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/783912b0fab66748):

```
false
false
```

What am I missing?

Comment: Highly related: https://stackoverflow.com/q/15036281/3002139

Answer (score 23, accepted):

String literals are lvalues ([expr.prim.general]/p1):

> A literal is a primary expression. Its type depends on its form (2.13). A string literal is an lvalue; all other literals are prvalues.

`decltype(expr)` returns an lvalue-reference when the expression `expr` is an lvalue expression ([dcl.type.simple]/p4):

> For an expression e, the type denoted by decltype(e) is defined as
>   follows:
>
> - if e is an unparenthesized id-expression or an unparenthesized class member access (5.2.5), decltype(e) is the type of the entity
>     named by e. If there is no such entity, or if e names a set of
>     overloaded func- tions, the program is ill-formed;
> - otherwise, if e is an xvalue, decltype(e) is T&&, where T is the type of e;
> - otherwise, if e is an lvalue, decltype(e) is T&, where T is the type of e;
> - otherwise, decltype(e) is the type of e.

String literals *are* arrays of `N` `const char`, but what you are experiencing is the effect of `decltype`. What you really have is the type `char const(&)[N]`, **not** `char const[N]`.

Simply removing the reference should give you the behavior you desire:

```
std::is_array<std::remove_reference_t<decltype("sss")>>::value;
```

Answer (score 7):

You have to remove the reference first, since the type deduced by `decltype` is `const char (&)[N]`, not just `const char [N]`:

```
std::cout << std::boolalpha << std::is_array<
    typename std::remove_reference<decltype("sss")>::type
>::value << '\n'; // true
```