# Is there any way to change char* value at any index?

Tags: c++, arrays, char

As I know, if we declare `char*` in our program then it gives memory from read-only area, so we are not able to change a `char` at any position in the array.

```
char *ch = "sitaram";
ch[2] = 'y';
```

The above code will not run properly, as we are changing read-only memory.

One approach is we can declare our `char` array as

```
char ch[] = "sitaram";
```

and then we can change a value at an index.

Is there any way where I can change a `char` value at any index in a `char*`?

Comment: `char *ch = "sitaram";` only compiles because of a backwards compatibility "feature". The correct type should be `const char *ch`. As the type implies, you cannot modify this string.

Comment: `char*` is a **pointer**. When you write `char *ch = "sitaram";` it initializes `ch` to **point to** the first element of an array of `char` that holds the string literal `"sitaram"`. That distinction is important; a pointer is not an array, and an array is not a pointer.

Comment: It is also important to make the distinction that `char*` itself is not what makes the memory read-only. The pointer is simply pointing at a read-only literal value. Make it point at writable memory instead and then modifying works. Changing `ch` to `char[]` instead of `char*` simply causes the literal data to be copied into the `char[]` memory during initialization.

Answer (score 6):

Use the modern C++ approach for mutable string values

```
std::string str{"sitaram"};
str[2] = 'y';
```

String literals (i.e. values enclosed in `""`) are by default of type `const char[n]` (where `n` is the length of the string literal `+1` for the null character)  in C++ and because of that they are immutable, any attempt to modify them results in [undefined behavior](https://blogs.msdn.microsoft.com/oldnewthing/20140627-00/?p=633).

Comment: _String literals (i.e. values enclosed in "") are by default of type const char*_ ... **nope**, they are of type [`const char[n]`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal) and only _decay_ to `const char*` in a context where a pointer is required.

Comment: @zett42 are they of type `const char[n]` or `const char (&)[n]`?  I feel like they are the latter?  https://wandbox.org/permlink/sQCCemUzweDCDLAM

Comment: From [cppreference](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/language/string_literal): _1) Narrow multibyte string literal. The type of an unprefixed string literal is const char[]._

Comment: @zett42 hmm I wonder why `decltype` evaluates to a reference to an array then

Comment: [Fascinating: _String literals are lvalues_](https://stackoverflow.com/a/30293277/7571258)

Answer (score 4):

When you say:

```
char *ch = "sitaram";
```

The compiler does the following:

- it allocates the string "sitaram" at program start (static storage duration). This string can be put into read-only memory.
- when your program arrives at this line, it allocates the pointer `ch`, and makes this pointer to point to the statically allocated "sitaram" string.
- if you do `ch[2] = 'y'`, then you're trying to modify the 3rd character of the statically allocated string. Usually, you get a crash (because it is in read-only memory)

On the other hand, if you do the following:

```
char ch[] = "sitaram";
```

When the program hit this line, it allocates memory for the array `ch[]` (for 8 chars), then copies the string "sitaram" into this memory. If you do `ch[2] = 'y'`, then you modify this allocated memory, which is perfectly fine to do.

If you want to modify a string with `char *`, it should point to a memory which is modifiable. For example:

```
char ch[] = "sitaram";
char *xx = ch;
xx[2] = 'y'; // it is the same as ch[2] = 'y';
```

Answer (score 2):

Using `char` arrays:

```
char text[] = "sitaram";
text[3] = 'o';
char * p = &text[0];
p[4] = 'x';
cout << text;
```

Answer (score -1):

its just idea:
you can copy whole value of char* ch into char array
change value of i symbol and put new string in another ch2
then take address of pointer ch and assign it to pointer ch2...
but probably it won't work...