# is a string converted to const char* in C++

Tags: c++, c++17

A string like "hello" would be `string` or `const char*`.
Consider an example:

```
template<typename A>
A s(A a){
    // ...
}
```

here what would be "hello" converted to, if I called `s("hello")`?

Comment: In C++ all literal strings are really constant arrays of characters (including the null-terminator). As any other array it can decay to a pointer to its first element. It will *never* automatically be converted to a `std::string`.

Answer (score 4):

A string like `"hello"` is a `const char[6]`. Since you can't pass an array by value, `A` will be deduced to `const char*` instead.

Answer (score 3):

When you are looking for a type you may use this trick :

Create a struct without implementation

```
template<typename A>
struct Error;
```

And use it :

```
template<typename A>
A s(A a){
    Error<A> error;
    return a;
}

int main()
{
    Error<decltype("error")> e; // error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Error<char const (&)[6]>'
    s("hello"); // error: implicit instantiation of undefined template 'Error<const char *>'
}
```

The error will give you the type you are looking for.

Tada! `"Hello"` type is  `char const [6]` but in the `s` the decuce type is `const char *`

---

Credit :

Effective Modern C++, Chapter 1. Deducing Types,  Item 4: Know how to view deduced types.

https://www.oreilly.com/library/view/effective-modern-c/9781491908419/ch01.html

Comment: Except that the answer is wrong - `"Hello"` type is not a `const char*`, but `const char[6]`. The link you provided explicitly warns against this mistake.

Comment: Edited, better now ?

Comment: Correct - this gives both answers. https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30293262/why-does-decltype-on-a-string-literal-not-yield-an-array-type explains why `decltype` gives that `(&)` bit in the first error message