# String literal type is not as expected

Tags: c++, c++11, char, string-literals, decltype

Consider the following program:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <type_traits>

int main(int argc, char* argv[])
{
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype("hello"), char*>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype("hello"), const char*>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype("hello"), char[5]>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype("hello"), const char[5]>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype("hello"), char[6]>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype("hello"), const char[6]>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype("hello"), char[]>::value << std::endl;
    std::cout << std::is_same<decltype("hello"), const char[]>::value << std::endl;
    return 0;
}
```

It returns only zeroes, while I would have expected `"hello"` to be a `const char[6]`. What is the type of `"hello"`?

Comment: [Hint](https://wandbox.org/permlink/dTF7wW5XSwwAbAqb).

Comment: One could even read this as a dupe of https://stackoverflow.com/q/15036281/3002139

Comment: Whenever you are wondering what `decltype(...)` is, it can be helpful to [get the compiler to tell you in an error message](https://wandbox.org/permlink/02pW8u0mTY9L57kS)

Comment: How about const char (&)[6]? static_assert(std::is_same<decltype("Hello"), char const (&)[6]>::value, "hrmm"); does not trigger using msvc17 with std set to latest.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Edit: I was too quick and didn't notice the `const char[6]`. Since none of your checks involve `&`:

Quoting [8.4.1 Literals](http://eel.is/c++draft/expr.prim#literal):

> A literal is a primary expression. Its type depends on its form. A
>   string literal is an [**lvalue**](http://en.cppreference.com/w/c/language/value_category); all other literals are prvalues.

Hence, the type is `const char (&)[6]`.

Comment: It's type **is** `const char[6]`, the reference is the effect of `decltype`. Please check my duplicate link in question comment.

Answer (score 1):

Type is `const char (&)[6]` as you can see [here](http://coliru.stacked-crooked.com/a/f87267ce33c85695)